# Adding style based on a tag in anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have some links in a list(`li`) there may be one,two or three `li` in the `ul`.
The `li` again has `<a>` and some anchors contains text or icons

### Here is codes

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">prev</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-left"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-left"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

### What i want

if there is both two `li` has i the `a` will have `border-radius:25px` but if there is one `i` and one `text` or both are text the `a` will have `border-radius:0px`

### Here is my try

```
var thumbLinkList = $('li');
var thumbLink = $('li a');
    thumbLink.each(function( index,elem ){
         if($(this).find('i')){
            if($(this).parent().siblings('li').find('i')){
                $(this).css({
                   'border-radius' : '25px'
                })
            }
          }
     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('ul').each(function() {
  
  if ($('i', $(this)).length > 1) {
    $('a',$(this)).css('border-radius','10px')
  }
  
});
```

```css
i, a {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">prev</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-left"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-left"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('ul').each(function(ind, ele){
    var $ul = $(ele),
        doRad = $ul.find('a > i').length > 1;
    if(doRad){
        $ul.find('a').css('border-radius', '25px');
    }
});
```